# Dropping the minimum values in long form

Tags: stata, reshape, long-integer, minimum

I am working with Stata on a dataset that has many farmer households which are repeated if they have multiple plots: For example like they have 3 plots in which they grow paddy.

Now I would like to find the min quantity of paddy among all the plots for a given household and then `drop` that row

How do I do this?

Example:

```
HHID Plot Qty
1     1    1
1     2    3
2     1    0.5
2     2    1
```

I want to `drop qty` 1 and 0.5 for household 1 and 2

so my table will be

```
HHID Plot Qty
1    2    3
2    2    1
```

Comment: How do you want to treat ties? For example, if `HHID` 2 owned two plots with  `Qty` 0.5 would you want to drop both? Or only one?

Answer (score 1):

```
bysort HHID (Qty) : drop if _n == 1
```

Comment: With reference to my comment above, something like `bysort HHID (Qty) : drop if Qty == Qty[1]` might be desirable if OP is concerned with ties.

Comment: I agree. Ties need attention.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful. What if I want to drop only if there at least two entries ie - I don't want to drop values with just one entry

Comment: Please edit your question to add your new question.